# Losing shape when separating faces with subsurf modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am making a car, and I would like to separate the different components such as the bumper, doors, etc. Ideally, I would like to keep the shape of the parts like so:

[image: Original Wheel Arch]

However, when I separate the faces, the arch loses its shape like so:

[image: Wheel arch deformed]

Is there any way to separate these faces without having to apply the subsurface modifier and keep the original shape?

[image: Current mesh]

Here is how the mesh currently looks.

Comment: Could you show the mesh?

Comment: Don't think that's possible. Even the modifier is applied you'll see seams if smooth shading.